# Basic html view in firefox browser

Tags: html, firefox, web, mozilla

How can i set basic html view as default in firefox web browser? I mean i want to open every web page in basic html form.

I know that gmail offers the basic html view but i want to set it for all other websites in my browser.

Comment: It's simple: you can NOT. The appearance of the website is controlled by the author, not you. To do this you would need some styles for sites, but it require separate style for each and every site on the web - not possible. Maybe you could tell us why do you need that feature?

Comment: actually i am a competetive programmer so i just need a website for reading text , that's why websites like hackerrank take a lot of time to open so i was thinking of a way to open these sites in basic html form

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about setting up apps on your computer can be asked at [su].

Answer (score -1):

Create a New HTML File, Write Basic HTML Structure, Save the File, Open the Firefox, View in Firefox

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It says they want to open every page with the setting.